# Escape XML Function in VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce, xml

Currently, every field I can output easily by modifying the sObject on the back-end with my controller by using the following code:

```
for(sObject example: ExamplesToHaveXML)
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldToFormat : fieldsToFormat) 
    {
        String formattingField = fieldToFormat.getFieldPath();
        if(example.get(formattingField) != null) 
           example.put(formattingField, ((String)example.get(formattingField)).escapeXml());
    }
```

Now, this works fine and dandy for writable fields, but not so much for non-writable fields, like formula fields.

So I was curious if there was a VisualForce equivalent to the `escapeXml` method in Apex. I mean, there should be, but that doesn't always mean there is with Salesforce.

Basically, I don't want to do the work around where I have to create a wrapper for the sObject. That's the last resort. It'll still work. I just want to generate my XML with the least amount of meddling possible.

**Update**

Since it still has the same issue when the output text escaped, I still have fields I need to format prior to displaying them on the page.

Here is my full controller:

```
public with sharing class ExampleResponseController 
{
    public List<String> ExampleFields { get; set; }
    public List<Example__c> ExamplesToHaveXML { get; set; }
    public String XMLHeadingInformation { get; set; }

    public ExampleResponseController(ApexPages.StandardSetController inheritedController)
    {
        Set<String> exampleFieldSet = new Set<String>();

        for(SObjectField field : Example__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
            exampleFieldSet.add(field.getDescribe().getName());

        //These fields are being omitted because they are formula fields
        //with <BR> tags in them.
        //Note: If I do not remove these fields, the who action crashes
        exampleFieldSet.remove('OmittingField1__c');
        exampleFieldSet.remove('OmittingField2__c');
        exampleFieldSet.remove('OmittingField3__c');

        ExampleFields = new List<String>(exampleFieldSet);
        Set<Id> recordIdsSelected = (new Map<Id, sObject>(inheritedController.getSelected())).keySet();
        XMLHeadingInformation = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';

        ExamplesToHaveXML = (recordIdsSelected.size() > 0) ?
            Database.Query('SELECT ' + String.join(new List<String>(ExampleFields), ', ') + ' FROM Example__c WHERE Id IN :recordIdsSelected') :
            Database.Query('SELECT ' + String.join(new List<String>(ExampleFields), ', ') + ' FROM Example__c');

        List<Schema.FieldSetMember> fieldsToFormat = sObjectType.Example__c.FieldSets.Text_Areas_to_Format.getFields();

        //Using a field set, I format ALL text fields that may cause an issue.
        for(sObject example : ExamplesToHaveXML)
            for(Schema.FieldSetMember fieldToFormat : fieldsToFormat) 
            {
                String formattingField = fieldToFormat.getFieldPath();
                if(example.get(formattingField) != null) 
                    example.put(formattingField, ((String)example.get(formattingField)).escapeXml());
            }
    }
}
```

This allows my VisualForce to stay *somewhat* simple:

```
<apex:page standardController="Example__c" extensions="ExampleResponseController" 
    recordSetVar="Examples"
    contentType="text/xml" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" cache="false" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!XMLHeadingInformation}" escape="false"/>
    <queryResult xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <apex:repeat value="{!ExamplesToHaveXML}" var="Example">
            <records xsi:type="sObject">
                <type>Example__c</type>
                <apex:repeat value="{!ExampleFields}" var="Field">
                    <apex:outputText value="<{!Field}>" rendered="{!Example[Field] != null}"/> 
                        <apex:outputText value="{!Example[Field]}"  rendered="{!Example[Field] != null}"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="</{!Field}>" rendered="{!Example[Field] != null}"/>
                    {!IF(Example[Field] == null, "<" + Field + " xsi:nil=\"true\"/>", "")}
                </apex:repeat>
            </records>
        </apex:repeat>
    </queryResult>
</apex:page>
```

Currently, aside from the omitted fields, this renders like I want. But, as soon as I add the formula field, BOOM! It blows up.

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of the XML string you are trying to display that is breaking the page? If I use outputText with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><br />` it works just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think that `<br>` tags in your formula fields are the problem, can you try to substitute them either in controller, or in `outputText` like this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(Example[Field], '<br>', '<br/>')}" 
    rendered="{!Example[Field] != null}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [apex:outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) to escape sensitive characters. You can use it like this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!record.field}" />
```

There's a parameter called "escape" that defaults to true; in other words, when you use this element, it naturally protects you from emitting characters that might be misinterpreted by an XML or HTML parser.

Comment: I did this and it still needed me to escape certain characters for some reason. Bug maybe? I'll add more information.

Comment: @ProgrammableMedley Yeah, we'll probably need more information, then.

Comment: Added a bit more information to guide the hunt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Apex there is a string.escapeXML() function. See the string class [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm). I'm not sure if this is your problem, but your code has some SOQL injection issues, as you define a public string setter in your controller that is passed to a database.query() statement without any sanitization.

Comment: It is to my understanding that the outputText escapes your output unless you specify otherwise. Only one line in my VisualForce do I have escaped set to false - which only I provide. It may be better to have a private set for that value, but I feel that would be splitting hairs.

Comment: No, the SOQL injection is in your controller. the output text is happening on your page. You cannot escape field names, you need to sanitize them by ensuring that they are field names that you can access and not SOQL code or fields that you shouldn't access. Escaping doesn't help at all here.

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce's escape function is **`HTMLENCODE(...)`**

We had the same issue in API v42.0 and found the problem in the ContentType attribute. To escape the output, all {!merge} fields outputted into the markup must be wrapped with HTMLENCODE.

Why? These content types DISABLE automatic escaping:

- text/xml
- application/xml
- application/html
- application/xhtml
- application/xhtml+xml

Even outputText with escape=true will do nothing in such pages.

---

These content types ENABLE automatic escaping:

- text/html
- text/xhtml
- text/xhtml+xml

But are mostly useless for document generation because they include Salesforce markup. Yes, even with sidebar=false and showHeader=false and applyHtmlTag=false and applyBodyTag=false, the XML output still contains head tags and instrumentation JavaScript.